# Having a responsive screen with two images taking 50% height

Tags: css

I have two images which should take half of both the screens but my second image is not coming properly.

I have used everything possible but its just not coming.

HTML PART :

```
<section id="genderSelection">
  <div id="yuko">
      <img class="image-gender" ng-click='genderController.onGirlClicked()'
        src="app/app_resources/icons/yuko.png">
  </div>
  <div id="cody"
        ng-click='genderController.onGuyClicked()'>
    <img class="image-gender"
      src="app/app_resources/icons/cody.png">
  </div>
</section>
```

My CSS :

```
.image-gender {
  width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

section {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#yuko {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

div#cody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

EDIT : The problem was that in my body tag overflow:hidden was used in some other part. Removing that I am able to see the second image while scrolling. But the situation is that UX is not good as the two images are not fixed and are scrollable. Is there any solution for that? I want the images to have the feel of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. I have used dummy images with your code. 
Improved the code with the an example you were asking for and this will also not stretch the images.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.CommonArea {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

div#yuko {
  background: #FF73AB;
}

div#cody {
  background: #00BDD3;
}

.image-gender {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

/* Responsive Css For Mobile Devices*/
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .image-gender {
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="genderSelection">
  <div id="yuko" class="CommonArea" ng-click='genderController.onGirlClicked()'>
    <img class="image-gender" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWVIY.png">
  </div>
  <div id="cody" class="CommonArea" ng-click='genderController.onGuyClicked()'>
    <img class="image-gender" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPBPZ.png">
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. The problem was that in my body tag overflow:hidden was used in some other part. Removing that I am able to see the second image while scrolling.

But the situation is that UX is not good as the two images are not fixed and are scrollable. Is there any solution for that? I want the images to have the feel of buttons

Comment: If you want to remove scroll and as I see your images you can take pink and skyblue color as background colors and then place the girl only and boy only  images ..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.image-gender {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#yuko, #cody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flex` property, although the children elements of the flex tag should have no `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` to avoid scroll bars.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    /* This one is for getting full page height to get a quick example, can omit in your code. */
    html,
    body {
      /* Box-model */
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      /* Box-model */
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    body,
    #one,
    #two {
      /* Box-model */
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #one,
    #two {
      /* Box-model */
      flex-basis: 50%;
    }

    #one {
      /* Visual */
      background-color: khaki;
    }

    #two {
      /* Visual */
      background-color: burlywood;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="one">This is paragraph one.</p>
  <p id="two">This is paragraph two.</p>
</body>
</html>
```